# Can reversible reactions proceed by different mechanisms in the forward and reverse directions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics

It seems odd to me that this would be the case, but it also seems odd that it wouldn't.
Imagine a mechanism for a (forward) reaction that includes a slow reversible step and a fast irreversible step:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{A &<=> B} &\quad &\text{(slow)} \\
> \ce{B &-> C} &\quad &\text{(fast)}
> \end{align}
> $$

If the second step is irreversible, it's presumably going to be highly unfavorable to run in the reverse direction, and so there ought to be some alternate mechanism with a lower $E_\mathrm{a}.$ Is it possible that the reverse reaction is more favorable by a different mechanism? If not, why not?

Comment: In the way you have written the reaction, as soon as B is formed it reacts to make C so  [B] $\approx 0$ and A is soon depleted.  To get C back to A then of course if the activation energy is absolutely vast it may take millenia, however, a completely different route may be possible not involving B. Most species have more than one way of being synthesised, particularly for organic species.

Comment: So you can have different mechanisms for each direction?

Comment: If the alternative mechanism is available in the reverse direction, it must also be available in the forward direction or you would be able to make a perpetual motion machine. So you can certainly have mulriple parallel reaction pathways, but both the forward and reverse direction will favor the pathway with lowest Ea.

Comment: As Andrew writes the reverse reaction is always there but one way to get back to A would involve using a catalyst. This now involves different chemistry to the forward step.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. An ideal Carnot cycle (admittedly not a reaction) illustrates how this is possible. In such a cycle each step is reversible. To return to a state you can either reverse the direction of the process (running say a heat engine as a refrigerator) or follow the full path of the cycle until the state is again encountered.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different answers, depending on whether you mean that the alternate pathway can occur in the same reaction mix (ie under the same conditions) as the described forward reaction is occurring.

If there is an alternate pathway possible under the same reaction conditions, it will be used for both the forward and reverse reactions. Due to the principle of microscopic reversibility, no reaction pathway can preferentially be used for one direction and not the other.

If you allow for alternative reaction conditions, then there are often multiple possible pathways to get from any A to B, especially if the reaction has more than one step. Even for a single-step reaction, a catalyst can be used to lower Ea (as noted in the comments on the question). Such a catalyst will necessarily lower Ea for both the forward and reverse reactions, though, so the equilibrium amounts of A, B and C in your example will be the same if the only difference in conditions is the presence of the catalyst.